# Rails 4 Routing Subdomain Constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, routes, subdomain, passenger

I have a rails application working in development mode with the routing configured as below:

```
  scope module: :web do
    resources :locations
  end


  constraints subdomain: "api" do
    scope module: :api do
      resources :locations
    end
  end
```

This works when starting the rails server and using www.lvh.me:3000 and api.lvh.me:3000 respectively. However this fails when running in production using apache and passenger, giving an `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/locations")` 
error when visiting either domain.

My apache vhost configuration file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.XYZ.co.uk
    ServerAlias *.XYZ.co.uk

    DocumentRoot /myapp/current/public

    <Directory /myapp/current/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Does anybody know what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Routes**

I would certainly look to remove the `www` constraint -

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints subdomain: "api" do
   scope module: :api do
     resources :locations
   end
end

scope module: :web do
   resources :locations
end
```

Unless you're attempting to *only* serve your app from the "www" subdomain, you'll be much better treating routes as being for the *entire* application, only using constraints to specify individual elements

--

**Apache**

You'll also want to ensure your subdomains are being caught correctly by Apache / Passenger:

```
#etc/apache2/apache2.conf
VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName XYZ.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.XYZ.co.uk

    DocumentRoot /myapp/current/public

    <Directory /myapp/current/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

What you need to remember is that when you send requests to your Rails app, it will take any of the constraints provided by the browser, and render the corresponding route. Apache is merely a gateway in this instance -- a way to connect your HTTP request and your backend application.

You should do as much as possible with the Rails routing system - meaning you should leave the `apache` conf file to pass forward the request, as opposed to trying to handle / route it.

Specifically, I don't believe you'll need to specify the `api` subdomain in your Apache config file. You'll just be better passing the traffic through to Rails itself

--

**Rails**

Finally, you mention you're receiving the `no route matches` error - you'll be able to look in the Rails logs at what the request actually was from Apache

I imagine your app will either not have passed the correct constraint, or your server's setup will be incorrect. You'll probably want to make sure your routes & Apache config are setup as above, and then update your question with the request Rails receives

Comment: Thanks I have removed the www constraint. It appears that all requests to the api subdomain are routed to the web namespace, rather then being handled by the controller in the api namespace.

Comment: Okay, we need to put the subdomain constraint first :)

Comment: Thanks- just tried that, but getting the same error.

Comment: Found the error by logging the subdomain on the server. Due the .co.uk domain, the actual subdomain reported by the server is "api.X" rather than just "api". Thanks for all your help.

Comment: No problem - you based in Chester? I'm on Wirral!